# Could not find UpdatePanel with ID on page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have below structure in my asp.net application.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div id="overlay"></div>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upProfile" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAttachment" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlSuccessMessage" runat="server" >
    <asp:Label ID="lblSuccessMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

I have different textfields and dropdowns in the table of upProfile updatepanel and file upload control in upAttachment updatepanel. Now when I select one radio from the same update panel, I am getting below error and the upAttachment does not show up on page.

> Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'MainContent_upAttachment'. If it is being updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.

I have searched a lot and tried below different things, but still it is not working
1. Set the upAttachment UpdateMode to Conditional.
- In this case, it does not throw error, but the file upload control which is inside that updatepanel, it does not show up
2. Place the upAttachment updatepanel inside another updatepanel, but that too is not working.

I don't know what to do in this case. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you post your code that accesses `MainContent_upAttachment`? I'm suspecting you are doing something wrong with it.

Comment: Hi Nisarg, which code should I post?

Comment: Your C# code that accesses these update panels.